# Sorting arrays alphabetically

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I've been looking for arrays sorting in Visual Basic.NET but my code always return null. I.e. i got a text file that contains:

```
Ahmed 50 (Not_available)
Thor 44 (Available)
Clark 85 (Not_available)
Sally 93 (Available)
```

I wanted to sort them by the first letter of the first word. So the output gonna be :

```
Ahmed 50 (Not_available)
Clark 85 (Not_available)
Sally 93 (Available)
Thor 44 (Available)
```

First i split them into array using `.Split(" ")` method. Then i use `.Trim()` to remove any return carriage. And at last, i sort them using `Array.Sort()`

There is my code :

```
Dim Data As String() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("store.txt").Split(vbCrLf)
Try
   For Count = 0 to Data.Length - 1
   Data(Count).Trim()
Next
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

Array.Sort(Data)
```

When i call an element using `MsgBox(Data(0))` it's return   empty.

Is/are there any mistakes i made in the code? Any response would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Using `ReadAllLines` will save you the work of having split the lines yourself (it returns an array where each line is an element in the array). Then all you need to  do is call sort on the provided array.... `Dim data As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("store.txt")`...
`Array.Sort(data)`

Comment: Incidentally, using an empty `Catch` statement will prevent it from telling you when someting goes wrong. You should not use Try...Catch unless it really is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one line:

```vb
Dim data = File.ReadLines("file path here").
                Select(Function(s) s.Trim()).
                OrderBy(Function(s) s).
                ToArray()
```

It's worth noting that you aren't actually trimming the data because that `Trim` method doesn't work in-place. It actually returns a new `String`, so you'd need to then assign that back to the array element.

Answer (score 0):

Empty `Catch` is bad. It just swallows errors and you don't know what has gone wrong.

Check the overloads of the `.Split` method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#overloads `vbCrLF` is really 2 characters. It is a string. Changing it to a `Char` array makes `Split` happy. Adding the optional `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` parameter removes the blank lines caused by splitting by both Cr (Carriage return) and Lf (Line feed)

With Option Strict off your method (without the conversion to Char array) produces odd results. Option strict should almost always be on.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim Data As String() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("store.txt").Split(vbCrLf.ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Array.Sort(Data)
    For Each s In Data
        Debug.Print(s) 'see results in Immediate Window
    Next
End Sub
```

Even simpler and more up to date is using System.IO File class. Replace the first line with

```
    Dim Data = File.ReadAllLines("store.txt")
```

and add

```
Imports System.IO
```

to the top of the file.